# What is the simplest way to add an profile image with the Omniauth-Facebook Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I'm working with the Omniauth Facebook Gem with Rails and need a profile pick on my app for each user.

Is it as simple as retrieveing the Name of the user from facebook with the Gem, or does it need to be uploaded to Amazon S3 servers etc.?

My user model:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
```

Can't find a clear answer.

Updated:
In my show page it only shows the url:

```
<b>IMAGE:</b> <%= @user.image %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple to do. And you don't require to store image on your server. You can simply fetch it from facebook.

Here is how I do it:
Add an `image` field in your `User` model:

```
rails generate migration addImageToUsers image:string
```

Add it `attr_accessible` list.

Then in your above method, add following listing for image:

```
user.image = auth.info.image
```

This is the direct url of where facebook stores the image of the user.

You can `inspect` your `auth` hash to study different size of user image.

Comment: I just figured it out thanks. Did exactly that! Yey. Except my show page show just the URL, not the image. I added the code above.

Comment: Ok got it <%= link_to image_tag @user.image %> ;)